# Right way to run an io bound task in fastapi

Tags: python, celery, fastapi

I am using fastapi to maintain a web service. There is an API exposed which calls another API for execution, waits for it to complete through some status check mechanism, and then updates the task status in a database.

I have been using the background task API from fastapi for running this operation as a background task. I noticed that background task is not very reliable in updating task status. The external API invocation takes over an hour at times for completion and my background task is essentially making status checks and its not a cpu intensive task.

What would be the right way to proceed in this case? Is background tasks appropriate here. I could see online folks suggesting celery, but i wonder if its an overkill since task is io bound and i would expect maybe a maximum of 100 such background tasks to be executed in a day.

Comment: Can I ask, why is the background task unreliable? It seems like a natural fit for your use case.

Comment: if you would put the code for the background task we might have an idea why it is unreliable

Comment: It is not making the database update intermittently because of the delay in status check. It could take over an hour for the task to be completed. 

Background task 

1) check the status of a task (external API) could take over an hour 
2) update database on status of task

Comment: Alright, it’s hard to understand what is taking an hour: your background task or the actual external API that is performing something. Background tasks can run however long you like (as long as your server is running of course).